# Does google cloud BigTable have a data browser?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I need to view the data in a BigTable table, but I can't find a data browser in the web console.  (Dynamo has a nice browser in the AWS web console.)  Is there a data browser for BigTable, or am I limited to the cbt command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: You can now view data in Bigtable using the [Bigtable Studio query builder](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/query-builder) in the cloud console. Go to your instance and select "Bigtable Studio" in the side navigation. You can select your table, filter on the rowkey, limit columns and query within a time range.

Previous response:

There is currently no data browser in the web console, so you're correct that you're limited to the cbt command line. One option that can help making viewing your data easier is to [query Bigtable through BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable). This can be great for one off ways you want to look at your data, but you should be careful with using it on any production data since some of the queries can easily do full table scans which impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to browser bigtable data via a UI would be to use a VSCode extension.
I built one sometime ago since I needed the same.
You can check this out if it solves your need.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=a7ul.vscode-bigtable